# Как преобразовать символьный поток в байтовый через InputStreamReader?

Tags: java, многопоточность, файлы

подскажите как преобразовать символьный поток в байтовый через InputStreamReader, читал что данный класс является мостом между двумя видами потоков, но как применять не понимаю.

```
public InputStream readerFromSymbolThreadToByte(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Reader reader = new FileReader(file);
        InputStream inputStream = new InputStreamReader(reader);
    }
```

Нет у него конструктора принимающий символьный поток.

Comment: И если кто может, обьясните вообще как работает InputStreamReader понятным для новичка языком. Он же символьного потока наследует, тогда каким образом он может преобразовать в байтовый поток и наоборот?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray(java.io.InputStream)

Answer (score 1):

Класс `InputStreamReader` предназначен для преобразования байтового потока в символьный, не наоборот, потому то у него и нет необходимого Вам конструктора. Для получения последовательности байтов из строки можете использовать метод `String.getBytes`.

Answer (score 0):

вот мой сохраненный кусок кода на чтение-запись файлов по байтам. помогло когда надо было скопировать *png файлы.

```
InputStream is = null;
OutputStream os = null;
try {
    is = getAssets().open("name");
    os = openFileOutput("name", MODE_PRIVATE);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        os.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
} finally {
    is.close();
    os.close();
}
```